# How to set a mini panel to display node fields?

Tags: 7, nodes, panels

I want to load node fields into a mini panel, but when I do what I think that I need to do, the mini panel (= MP) is invisible (because the fields aren't displayed, I guess).

So far I have:

- Added a Content Type
- Added fields to that Content Type
- Created a Minipanel with Required Context = Node
- Added my various Node Fields to that MP: Add Content > Node > Field: ___
- Moved the MP into my Content range in the Blocks Editor

I don't see my MP anywhere. [This user seems to have a similar issue](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/16633), and solved it with the Context settings but doesn't answer the question at all, just closed it.  Other people seem to have this issue as well:

- [Can't get a mini panel containing node form fields into a panel page](http://drupal.org/node/829202)
- [Node fields and node tokens not showing up in a mini-panel](http://drupal.org/node/1227606)

Can anyone clarify for me how to make my MPs show up with information populated from the node?

Comment: The easiest way of trying to debug this, is to add a custom text-field to the MP, and enter panels specific tokens into it, such as `%node:nid`, and see if they get replaced. If not, you have a context problem. Otherwise, it's likely a formatter/rendering problem.

Comment: I would first try removing the "Node" required context and see if that renders the block. Make it work at the most basic level possible and then add various customisations and contexts.

Answer (score 0):

As per Beebee comment, you should first try removing the "Node" required context and see if that renders the block. Make it work at the most basic level possible and then add various customisations and contexts.

Answer (score 0):

As per Letharion comment, the easiest way of trying to debug this, is to add a custom text-field to the MP (mini panel), and enter panels specific tokens into it, such as `%node:nid`, and see if they get replaced. If not, you have a context problem. Otherwise, it's likely a formatter/rendering problem.

Answer (score -5):

While you can have nodes in block, you can put it in your panel.

- [nodeblock](http://drupal.org/project/nodeblock)
- [nodesinblock](http://drupal.org/project/nodesinblock)
- [nodeasblock](http://drupal.org/project/nodeasblock)

Comment: I don't think that answers the question at all, or I don't understand, can you be more specific?